# Service call in localhost host works fine but when done using ionic it adds &amp; in the url

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am making call to external library using two params. When I call it from my localhost or postman it works fine. But when I do ionic run android or ionic run ios. The request is being send service by adding & between the request params.

It goes like http://www.example.com/username=jamili&password=xxx
It should actually go like http://www.example.com/username=jamili&password=xxx

& is getting converted to &

I tried $httpParamSerializerJQLike but it did not work

Can anyone hep me out.

Comment: Sorry the url is getting appended with '&amp;' rather than &

Comment: Edit your question please to reflect and can you show the code used to make these calls

Comment: method: 'GET',
      url: ForbelsApi + '/webservices/authUser.php',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      params: requestParams
      // paramSerializer: '$httpParamSerializerJQLike'